# What is wrong with the following reasoning?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

**Problem:** If $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathrm{Re}(z^n) \ge 0$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, show that $z \in \mathbb{R}^+.$

**My attempt:**
We have to show that if $$\mathrm{Re}(z^n)=\mathrm{Re}(r^n \ \mathrm{cis}(n\theta))=\mathrm{Re}(r^n(\cos n\theta + i \sin n \theta))=\mathrm{Re}(r^n \cos n\theta)=r^n \cos n\theta=(a^2+b^2)^{n/2}\cos(n \theta) \geq 0,$$

then $a>0,b=0.$ Note that $$(a^2+b^2)^{n/2}\cos(n \theta) \geq 0 \implies \cos(n \theta) \geq 0 \implies \cos\left[n \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\right]\geq 0 \implies \\ 2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq \left[n \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\right] \leq 2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}, k \in \mathbb{Z}.$$ Since the above is true for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, it has to be true in particular for $k=1$, i.e., $\left[n \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\right] \geq \frac{3\pi}{2}.$ So $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$ has to be positive. So $\frac{b}{a}>0$ So $b>0.$

But this contradicts the problem statement?!

Comment: $Re(z^n) \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ or for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$? And if you take $z=0$, you have $Re(z^n) \geq 0 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, but $0 \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ is false.

Comment: The problem statement has been edited to say "every $n$", but your point is still valid...

Comment: The problem statement in the book is wrong - it should say "show that $z \in \mathbb{R}^{\ge 0}$"

Comment: The condition $Re(z^n) \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ implies $n\theta \in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now try to explain why $\theta$ must be zero.

Comment: you might want to look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104443/prove-that-if-rezn-geq-0-for-every-positive-n-then-z-in-mathbb-c-is-po/) for a different approach to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality
$$
2k\pi - \frac\pi 2 \leq ... \leq 2k \pi + \frac\pi 2
$$
is true for *some* $k$, not for *all* $k$.

Comment: By some $k$, you mean $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ right?

Comment: Yes, I mean $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Apart from that minor change, what is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Nothing else is wrong, keep going and try to show that if $\theta$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$ then $z^n$ will have nonzero imaginary part for some $n$. Then assume $\theta$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$ and try to widdle down your choices.